# Connecting PHP through xAMPP/MAMP to mySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mamp

I can connect to phpMyAdmin database through both xAMPP and MAMP from my php code. I can successfully insert data into my database but it sends it to the database in PHPMyAdmin which is completely different from the database that I want to send it to which is in MySQL. I want it to insert it into the table in MySQL. Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: phpMyAdmin is *not* your database. MySQL is. phpMyAdmin is just a tool to make managing your database easier. That's a very basic fundamental distinction that you should know *before* you start working with databases.

Comment: @john conde Yeah, I'm kind of new to using the programs. Can you explain why the database in phpMyAdmin is completely different?

Comment: You must just be connecting to different databases. Check your code that establishes the db connection. Check your phpMyAdmin connection settings. Are you connecting to the same server? Are you opening the same database on that server? Do your queries specify a database prefix? (`INSERT INTO dbname.tablename` for instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both XAMPP and MAMP assume that they will be providing everything for your installation. This means that XAMPP is running it's own web server and database server and MAMP is running it's own web server and database server.

Each database server (the one under XAMPP and the one under MAMP) has it's own databases, tables, etc and making changes on one does not carry over to the other.

For them to both see the same databases and tables, you need to either:

a) Configure both XAMPP and MAMP to connect to the same database server (whether it be the one for XAMPP or MAMP is your choice).

b) Do some complicated replication between to two servers (yes, they may be running on the same physical machine, but each runs it's own database server process)

c) Setup MySQL separate from XAMPP and MAMP and direct the two to use the separate MySQL database.

As it's been noted phpMyAdmin is **NOT** a database. It is a web application that connects to a MySQL database (much like your website) to provide an easy to use interface for managing the underlying SQL database.

**EDIT:**

If you are trying to connect to a database programmatically via PHP, you have two options:

**mysqli**

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("example.com", "user", "password", "database");
```

**PDO**

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=example.com;dbname=database', 'user', 'password');
```

There is an article on PHP.net that compares features of the different APIs that you should consult:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

From there, you will need to consult the PHP documentation as to how to read from and write to the database.

Comment: Yeah I understand it's not a database now, but what I meant was that phpMyAdmin is using a different database than the one I want. How can I connect it to the database I'm using in MySQL?

Comment: @Steven Do you mean connecting to the database via the command line / terminal or connecting via PHP?

Comment: @Steven Updated my answer.

Comment: I already have that PHP code portion. It just seems to connect to some other database, not the one that I want.

Comment: @Steven You might look in the `config.inc.php` file for phpMyAdmin to see how it's connecting to the database and replicate that to your PHP code.

Comment: I tried changing the socket to redirect to the mysql database that I want, but it keeps refusing my connection. "phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection." I also get these other two errors "mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client"

Comment: @Steven Looks like the server you want to connect to might be using a different authentication method: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/caching-sha2-pluggable-authentication.html